# Running mocha test inside gradle task

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, gradle, mocha.js

I have a mocha test which I want to run inside gradle task.

When I run it standalone I get a nice output like this:
[image]

But when I run it through gradle I get output like this:
[image]

I managed to display characters correctly although without colors. What is bothering me is that the output is not complete. Also output lenght is different each time I run the task. This makes me believe that this happens because test script is ran asynchronously inside node.js

Is there a way to fix this in gradle?

Comment: Could you add your build.gradle (or the interesting snippets thereof)